# Android как парсить xml по ссылке (XmlPullParserFactory)

Tags: android, xmlparser, java

Доброго времени суток, возникла необходимость распарсить XML
[допустим, с этой страницы](http://blog.ucoz.ru/api/blog/fotobanki/2014-03-24-315).
Но я никак не могу найти в интернете как в объекту класса XmlPullParser передать содержимое XML файла. Где-то на StackOverflow накопал такой код:

```
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        URL url = new URL("http://blog.ucoz.ru/api/blog/fotobanki/2014-03-24-315");
        InputStream stream = url.openStream();
        xpp.setInput(stream, null);
```

Но так не работает, ибо приложение падает сразу при запуске. Имеется
[Logcat](http://rghost.ru/private/53465160/a079d35a9cacf4ec5e28e6d2cdbff383)

Прошу помочь в данном вопросе. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: а в логкате черным по белому написано:    
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException    
что переводится как "Ошибка: Операции с сетью в главном потоке!"    
Что в свою очередь значит, что нельзя выполнять операции с сетью в главном потоке. Их нужно выносить во второстепенные потоки, на пример, при помощи AsyncTask

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, пойду гуглить))

Comment: остальное, вроде, у вас правильно. Нужно только вынести обработку во второстепенный поток.

Comment: Можно тогда еще вопрос? Вот, допустим, я распарсил нужный мне документ. А как тогда передавать полученные данные в новое Activity? С Intent'ом разобраться не получается. Можете написать простенький пример?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Можно тогда еще вопрос? Вот, допустим, я распарсил нужный мне документ. А как тогда передавать полученные данные в новое Activity? С Intent'ом разобраться не получается. Можете написать простенький пример?"

посоветую посмотреть этот [урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AI-mYBnqs7w&index=9&list=PLyfVjOYzujuitvmO3ttzfXFRldfS863RX)

Вообще у него много полезных уроков по Андроиду, сам с них начинал

Comment: Этот урок я читал. Вся проблема в том, что не могу никак взаимодействовать с основным "потоком". Уже не знаю как выкручиваться.

Comment: @Алексей Филиппович  
ты AcyncTask используешь? он же может возвращать данные в основной поток.

Comment: Ну, теперь пытаюсь вернуть данные, и вдруг, не работает сам парсер... не понос, так золотуха))